# Not seeing IIS related messages in Event Log

Tags: iis, windows-event-log

We've got a problem with a web service that we think is causing the app pool to restart itself but we're not seeing a message in the event log.  This raises the question of whether or not our hypothesis is correct.  So two questions really...

1. Should we be seeing a message of some sort in the event log related to IIS?  Even a "Hey I started and everything is great!" because we're not.  We see 0 messages related to IIS in our event logs.
2. If we should be seeing a message what can we do to start seeing messages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*From my answer on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/302110/what-causes-an-application-pool-in-iis-to-recycle/305966#305966)*

> You might want to turn on full AppPool
>   Recycle Event logs:
>
> ```
>  cscript adsutil.vbs Set w3svc/AppPools/DefaultAppPool/LogEventOnRecycle 255
> ```
>
> You also might want to take a look at
>   this Scott Guthrie blog article:
>   http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/12/14/433194.aspx
>   that shows how to write code in
>   Global.ASAX to log the actual cause of
>   an Application.End event.
>
> This has been extremely useful to us
>   in diagnosing several screwy issues -
>   one in partictual was an app that was
>   writing log files to the wwwroot
>   directory - too many file changes
>   resulting in a recycle...

Comment: Turning on those logs won't really make a difference since we can't see any logs in the event log or am I looking somewhere else for them? 

The Scott article sounds useful though..

Comment: LogEventOnRecycle=255 will turn on full logging on AppPool Recycling.  If this is set to 0, then you won't be getting any logging.

Comment: Made the change and we still get no logs...